# Iphone TableView parsing json

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

Anyone please can help me with something like this?
I need to parse info from mysql/php in order to create a photogallery for each product!

Thanks!

http://codecanyon.net/item/galleries-reloaded/473922?ref=mythodeia&ref=mythodeia&clickthrough_id=72212227&redirect_back=true

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SBJSON` API to parse the JSON response from your server, and set that output to the table view cell's `text` property in the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Hey thanks :) , can i please ask you something!
let say, after i parse the json file  into a table view, each time i click on a cell, which contains i.e the name of a car, i need to see after clicking it a gallery, image gallery! should i insert in the json array images for each car?...